# VBA: Loop with if condition only works correctly until the first TRUE

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am currently coding a loop in VBA and for some reason it only works until the first "If" statement is true. After that, it also applies the macro to cells that are FALSE. I just don't find the cause of this. In my example, operations 1.-3. should only be performed for x = 12 and x = 25 yet the code performes the macro for all x >= 12 and x <= 25

I've been trying for a good three hours now to fix this code and find an answer somewhere on the Internet... :-( Would be very happy if you could help! Thanks a lot in advance!

```
Sub CreateReport()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Long

lastrow = Sheets("Overview").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 10 To lastrow

    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

        '1. Copy sheet once per visible row

        Sheets("Master").Select
        Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        '2. Paste company name

        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = Sheets("Overview").Cells(x, 1).Value

        '3. Name worksheet after company name

        ActiveSheet.Name = Cells(4, 1).Value

    End If


Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case study as to why "ActiveSheet" should not be used.  The problem is that you set the newly created sheet sheet as the "ActiveSheet", so it starts checking the newly created sheet to see if any rows are hidden, and they aren't.  Specify the variables:

```
Sub CreateReport()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim overviewSheet As WorkSheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set overviewSheet = wb.Sheets("Overview")
Set masterSheet = wb.Sheets("Master")
lastrow = overviewSheet.Cells(overviewSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 10 To lastrow

    If overviewSheet.Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

        '1. Copy sheet once per visible row


        masterSheet.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

        Set newSheet = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

        '2. Paste company name

        newSheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = overViewSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value

        '3. Name worksheet after company name

        newSheet.Name = Cells(4, 1).Value

    End If


Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response and for your time! I was looking in all the wrong places... Now the macro's working just as I wanted it to :)